# How to disable Notifier in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

How to disable notifier? Sorry for stupid question,but i don't know how this tool calls,for searching in Google.I tried Notifier,Helper etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the name it looks like this window belongs to [CodeRush Intellassist](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CodeRush/CustomDocument6524).

So remove CodeRush or look in the CodeRush options to disable such messages.